# SQLite upsert: get last inserted or edited rowid

Tags: php, sqlite

Let's say I have an unique key on `email` attribute on `users` table and I want to store or update users data who just logged in:

```
INSERT INTO users (email, count) VALUES('john@doe.com',0)
ON CONFLICT(email) DO UPDATE SET count=count+1
```

Now in PHP I can use [lastInsertRowID()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.lastinsertrowid.php) to retrieve inserted rowid, but what if `ON CONFLICT` clause is triggered? Can I obtain the relevant rowid (inserted or updated) more elegantly than running additional select?

I see no mention about that [in the reference](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html).

Comment: Why do you need to know the rowid here in the case of an upsert?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen in my use case, the user can log in via password or some OAuth provider. I want to store that information to the user record to link his accounts together. Now when he logged in (maybe just added into the database if logged by provider for the first time), I want to get his rowid, because when he creates some content I would like to perform a simple insert without the need of joining the users table doing that.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the INSERT OR REPLACE statement to write new rows or replace existing rows in the table. The syntax and behavior of the INSERT OR REPLACE statement is similar to the INSERT statement. Unlike the INSERT statement, the INSERT OR REPLACE statement does not generate an error if a row already exists.

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO users (email, count) 
VALUES ('john@doe.com', IFNULL((SELECT count FROM users WHERE email = 'john@doe.com'), 0) + 1)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: nice idea, but when I do a INSERT OR REPLACE, in case the record already exists, it will be replaced, and get a new rowid/id/primary key. This might be possible to handle, but if you don't this breaks associations